# Enabled WiFi leads to complete freeze

Tags: wireless, freeze

I am running a Dual-Boot system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23 on Dell Latitude 7490. It is fresh installed and used to work. However, since around 1 month I encounter the following problem when trying to log into Ubuntu: The system freezes completely and does not react to anything, most of the time already on the log in screen but at least after some seconds after login.

After some testing, I could track this issue back to the running WiFi. When switching it off using the console in recovery mode, resuming normal boot and using an ethernet connection (like right now) I am not experiencing any problems.

Any advice how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. It also failed with Ubuntu 22.04

Here my lshw output:

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: 3c:6a:a7:92:18:55
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-35-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:ec000000-ec001fff
```

Comment: Please clarify your details; there is no Ubuntu 23 and the *year* format products (eg. Ubuntu Core 22) are *snap* only being released only on *even* years, so do you mean Ubuntu 23.04? or Ubuntu 23.10?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 23.04.
Funnily enough, it seems to work now after having the wifi switched on and off multiple times over the last weeks and rebooting multiple times. Not sure if the Upgrade to 23.03 helped, since it also froze some times with this version.

So, thread can be closed for now. Unfortunately I cannot share the solution to this problem.

Comment: After trying again today, it froze again when starting normally. At least it seems to work when I starting using the recovery mode, enable wifi and then resume normal boot.

Comment: Ok, the problem was caused bei the power save mode of the intel driver. Here an explanation including the solution: https://paperstack.com/fixing_the_freeze/

Comment: Absolutely same problem. I catched moment - when wi-fi got connected to network - dead freeze happening. In recovery mode i delete netplan yml of knowing wi-fi network and it's start to boot as usual. Seems like it's Power Management game of my Lenovo 20160 (v580c). But it worked fine before couple days. Trying to solve it. PS Can't comment start message (reputation of newbie)